# For Loop Program for Distance calculation

Tags: matlab

I have a question about for loop; I have to calculate the shortest “physical distances” and “allocation” for each cell in a raster matrix as given below and I developed the code but there comes the error in distance calculation....
please help me.

```
Raster = [1 0 0 1 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 1 0 0 1;0 0 0 0 0 0;0 1 0 0 0 0];
[i,j] = find(Raster==1);
[nrow,nclon] = size(Raster);
Dist = zeros(nrow,nclon);
D = 1;
% Cell Size = 1m
for ii = 1:6
   for jj = 1:6
      E(ii,jj) = (((ii-i)^2 +(jj-j)^2)^0.5)*D
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read your error message:

```
Error using  ^ 
Inputs must be a scalar and a square matrix.
To compute elementwise POWER, use POWER (.^) instead.
```

What you probably want to do is calculating the elementwise distance to each `1` in `Raster` and taking the minimum of it:

```
E(ii,jj) = min(((ii-i).^2 +(jj-j).^2).^0.5*D);
```